# Faulty hard drive - want to recover

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, bsod

I have a hard drive that will cause the page fault in non paged area BSOD at bootup;

there is a partition in there that i want to retrieve but am unable to because it gets into the blue screen - am using Windows 10

this isn't even the boot drive, so I don't even know why it is causing this error.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this to load after windows is loaded to so i can run recovery programs on it?

i've tried hot swapping it after boot up but that didn't work

it's a regular sata hard drive 3tb with a lot of important files

i should've backed this up and it would have been but my friend paid for crappy onedrive , believing that unlimited backup would've been offered by now (it isn't) : so i only backed up part of it

Comment: Put it in a USB enclosure. That's my standard way of recovering bad drives. SMART won't get in the way & I've had drives that would crash the OS be just fine to work on over USB

Comment: This sounds like probably the best idea.. Thanks for the suggestion.. Sometimes it takes someone stating the obvious to you before it becomes really obvious :)